# skype not installing

Tags: software-installation

Skype is not installing in my Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install skype
giving following output.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: ia32-libs (>= 20080808) but it is not going to be installed
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick/partner amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_maverick_partner_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

please help

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and than again :

```
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: i did it . even then it is not getting installed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you are trying to install a 32-bit package on a 64-bit machine. ia32-libs make it possibe to install 32-bit on 64-bit. Type "ia32" in Softwarecenter and install packages. Afterwards try again to install Skype. 
Or try to reinstall ia32-libs, if you have them already installed.
Or download 64-bit package, if it is available.

Comment: sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu*.deb
[sudo] password for dell: 
Selecting previously unselected package skype.
(Reading database ... 175192 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking skype (from skype-ubuntu-quantal_4.1.0.20-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
 skype depends on libasound2 (>= 1.0.23).
 skype depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~).
 skype depends on libc6 (>= 2.7).
 skype depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
 skype depends on libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.5.3).
 skype depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0).
 skype depends on libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3).

Comment: skype depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1).
 skype depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0).
 skype depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36).
 skype depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6).
 skype depends on libx11-6.
 skype depends on libxext6.
 skype depends on libxss1.
 skype depends on libxv1.
 skype depends on libssl1.0.0.

Comment: dpkg: error processing skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype

Comment: I think you should upgrade your system.